# Is there any evidence that summary headings affect either SEO or user retention?

Tags: seo, content

Many sites use key item Summary or Takeaway "headings" that summarize a blog page's content.  You can see an example at [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/long-term-impacts-of-the-covid-19-k-shaped-recovery-5200711) (see section "Key Takeaways").  They will have short bullet points taken from the article and summarizing the  article content.

Is there any evidence that these summaries either help with SEO or help with user retention?

Comment: I doubt that it has anything to do with SEO.   I first saw that type summary in Discover magazine when I was a teenager in the mid-1990s.  I personally hate them.  It's kinda like the TL;DR (too long; didn't read) that people summarize posts with sometimes.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller interesting that you don't like them.  I personally liked reading the front page of the Wall Street Journal because it had summaries for their articles.  It was more than click bait, and you instantly knew if you wanted to read the rest of the article.